# Apply a conditional to struct and produce list that of struct type

Tags: struct, lambda, racket

I'm trying to write a function to produce a list of a define struct type based on a conditional but can only get it to produce the full struct instead of just the name.

Here's my attempt that produces the entire struct..

```
(define-struct birthday (name day month)#:transparent)

(define (bdayRange startday endday lst)
      (filter (lambda (x) (<= startday (birthday-day x) endday)) lst))
```

Not sure how to get the function to produce the birthday-name parameter given a list of birthday structs and the range of the days of the month from 1 to 30. I feel like the solution to this is obvious but I just can't figure it out.

Here's my attempt..

```
(define (bdayRange startday endday lst)
      (filter (lambda (x) (if (<= startday (birthday-day x) endday) (birthday-name x) '()) lst))
```

Would the better approach be to parse the list of structs for the birthday-name or encapsulate the range conditional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just `map` over the filtered list of `birthday` structures with `birthday-name`?

```
(define (bdayRange startday endday lst)
  (map birthday-name
       (filter (lambda (x) (<= startday (birthday-day x) endday)) lst)))
```

This returns a list of `name`s in the given range:

```
scratch.rkt> (define bday-list (list (birthday 'sam 25 'april)
                                     (birthday 'erin 15 'april)
                                     (birthday 'james 3 'april)
                                     (birthday 'randi 7 'april)))
scratch.rkt> (bdayRange 6 17 bday-list)
'(erin randi)
```

Comment: Had no idea I could do that